# Problem with iFrame in React rendering another app (flutter app)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flutter, iframe

I have a React app that is using an iFrame to render another app that was made in flutter (see the first image):
[image: React app: dashboard with iFrame]

The flutter app is hosted in a certain domain (so it's like a micro frontend). The app in React is the dashboard and is hosted somewhere else (different than the flutter app)

My problem is that when testing the flutter app directly in the hosted URL, it works as expected. When you click on the name of one person, a sidebar opens with some information and a button "Gestion oferta". [image: Sidebar]

When you click on the button, it should take you to this other view:
[image: visor de solicitud]

So this works as expected if I test the flutter app directly in the URL where it is hosted, but when I click on that button inside the react dashboard, it does not behave as expected, it just shows another instance of the same react app (dashboard) inside the iFrame, like this:
[image: dashboard cone]

Here is my code for this component in the react app that renders the iFrame, in which I call the URL for the flutter app:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { css } from '@emotion/react'
import Head from "next/head";
import DashboardLayout from "../../../layouts/DashboardLayout";
import { getTenantByCompanySiap } from "../../../helpers/tentant";
import { UAT, PROD, getEnv } from "../../../helpers/env";
export { getSSProps as getServerSideProps } from '../../../lib/Page'

export default function NuevaSolicitudPage(props) {

    const tenant = getTenantByCompanySiap(props.infoRh?.codeCompanySIAP)
    const branch = props.infoRh?.codeBranch
    const user = props.employeeData?.email

    const getCampanas = () => {
        const env = getEnv();
    
        const url = {
        [UAT]: `https://url-for-testing`,
        [PROD]: `https://other-url-for-production`
        };
    
        return url[env] || url[UAT];
    };

    const url = getCampanas()

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>Gestión de cartera | Campañas</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <DashboardLayout 
                {...props}
                title="Campanas"
            >
                <iframe
                src={url}
                css={css`
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                `}
                frameBorder="0"
                />
            </DashboardLayout>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

I do not have access to the flutter app code, I only consume it and show it in the iFrame, but I heard from someone that I need to configure some files in order to display flutter apps in an iFrame in react, but he is also not sure. I have searched for something like this but could not find anything relevant to this problem because the app is showing, it just does not behave as expected.

Can somebody give me an advice on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue had to do with the cookies, somehow the cookie to store the user session got lost/erased, so whenever you have something similar and you use cookies for user sessions, check if they are stored and used properly.